# Why does a local pointer to a variable defined inside a function have the same address?

Tags: c

The problem is that local pointer variables to the struct appear to have the same address, although they are defined locally within each function.

The question is why they are appearing to share a memory location (attached debugger screenshots), and how can they have their own unique memory allocation.

```
typedef struct Map Map;

struct Map {
    const char *key;
    const void *value;
    Map *next;
};

void testPut() {
    struct Map *map; 

    Test test1 = {"name1", 1};
    Test test2 = {"name2", 2};
    Test test3 = {"name3", 3};
}

void testGet() {
    struct Map *map; //this seems to have same address as map in testPut

    Test test1 = {"name1", 1};
    Test test2 = {"name2", 2};
    Test test3 = {"name3", 3};
}
```

**testPut**

[image]

**testGet**

[image]

Comment: What is the problem and what is the question? And how are addresses and reusability related?

Comment: Please do not share code as images.

Comment: you can't show memory address in the debugger without images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pointers are located on the stack. Both functions seem to have the same stack size. If you call them one after another the first variable of the second function will *probably* have the same address as the first variable of the first call.

So when you jump into `testPut()` the stack is increased by (i do not exactly know, but assume) 8bytes.
When the function is exited, the stack gets decreased by those 8bytes again.
And when you then access `testGet()` the stack for that function is created with the same size as `testPut()`. Then the address in `testPut()` and `testGet()` are the same.

The address should change if you try to:

- add a simple `int foo;` in front of `struct Map *map;` in `testGet()` or
- as stated in the comments put a `static` in front of the struct

Comment: Will *probably* have the same address, but don't count on it.

Comment: Correct. For illustration purposes, one can declare the variables as `static` and see that they get different addresses.

Comment: Thanks @nielsen for the workaround.

Comment: @Beta: absolutely. I've added that

Answer (score 2):

When an object is defined inside a function without `static`, `extern`, or `_Thread_local`, it has *automatic storage duration*. This means memory is reserved for it only until execution of its associated block ends. When the function returns, the memory may be reused for other purposes.

You have examined calls to `testGet` and `testPut` at different times. The memory is simply being used for one purpose at one time and a different purpose at another time.

Answer (score 2):

The local variables in `testPut` and `testGet` appear to have the same address in memory because they have automatic storage, hence are created on the stack upon entering each function (by code at the beginning of the function) and both functions happen to be called with the same stack depth and define the same local variables.

This is completely circumstantial, these addresses may change:

- if you call `testPut()` or `testGet()` from another place in your program
- if you run the program another time on modern OSes that implement address space randomisation
- if you compile with a different compiler or just different flags.
- if you change something in the rest of these functions
- if you change something elsewhere in the program
- if anything else happens or does not happen...

It is educational to try and understand how objects and statements are implemented in memory and code, it will help grab the concept behind pointers, but remember that none of this is defined by the C Standard, ony the semantics of the abstract machine.